# Replace specific values in a data frame with column mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to replace the `value 7` with the round number of mean of its columns with out `other 7` in that columns. Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['b'] =[3, 0, -1]
df['c'] = [4, 7, 6]
df['d'] = [7, 7, 6]

  a     b   c   d
0   1   3   4   7
1   2   0   7   7
2   3   -1  6   6
```

And here is the output I want:

```
  a     b   c   d
0   1   3   4   2
1   2   0   3   2
2   3   -1  6   6
```

For example, in row 1, the mean of column c is equal to 3.33 and then its round is 3, and in column column d is equal to 2 (since we do not consider the other 7 in that column).

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: for column 'c', you add non 7 values (6+4=10) and divide by 2 to get 5. But for col 'D', you're dividing 6 by 3 to get 2. why is that so?

Comment: Yes. I just edited a typo in the question. Since I want to replace all 7 with other values.

Comment: the calculation for col 'c' and 'd' are not consistent. for col'd', it should be 6 to be consistent with col'c' or col'c' be 3.33

Comment: You right. I just edited again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# replace 7 with np.nan
df.replace(7,np.nan, inplace=True)

# fill NaN values with the mean of the column
(df.fillna(df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(np.nan, 0)
                    .mean(skipna=False)  ))
 .round(0)
 .astype(int))
```

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   3   4   2
1   2   0   3   2
2   3   -1  6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
temp = df.replace(to_replace=7, value=0, inplace=False).copy()
df.replace(to_replace=7, value=temp.mean().astype(int), inplace=True)
```